# Unable to get the page when registering

Tags: java, spring

[image]

[image]

with a successful registration, an email arrives where you need to follow the link, that is, it must open HTML where it says the message about successful registration is written, the link for which you need to go through is generated using an activation key, which is UUID, the problem begins here, by email A message comes with a link, but under this link there is no HTML, I suppose the problem is in GetMapping

with authentication like problems no, everywhere permilAll

[image]

[image]

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/doRegist", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@RequestBody User user, BindingResult bindingResult) throws  Exception{
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throw new Exception("Ошибка Регистрации");
    }

    if(!userService.addUser(user)){

        return "User exist";
    }

    return "dashboard";
}


 @GetMapping(value = "/activate/{code}")
//@RequestMapping(value = "activation/{code}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String activate(ModelMap model, @PathVariable String code) {
    boolean isActivated = userService.activateUser(code);
    if (isActivated) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "User Successfully activated");
    } else
        model.addAttribute("message", "Activation code not found");
    return "verification";
}

 public class UserService {
public boolean addUser(User user){
    User userFromDb = repository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
    if (userFromDb!=null){
        return false;
    }
    user.setActive(true);
    user.setActivationCode(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    repository.save(user);
    if (!org.springframework.util.StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getEmail())) {
        String message = String.format(
                "Hello," + user.getUsername() + "!\n" + "Welcome.Please, visit http://localhost:9009/activate/%s",
                user.getActivationCode());
        mailSenderService.send(user.getEmail(), "Activation code", message);
    }
    return true;
}


public boolean activateUser(String activationCode) {
    User user = repository.findByActivationCode(activationCode);
    if(user == null){
        return false;
    }
      user.setActivationCode(null);

    repository.save(user);
    return true;

}
```

Comment: can you share the email body what you are receiving?

Comment: I added a screenshot called the result

Comment: Please add codes not screenshots!

Comment: you can check added